# module-info.java - error: jdk.crypto.mscapi cannot be resolved to a module

Tags: java, module-info

Eclipse version: Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)

JDK: 17.0.3

I'm making some updates to an existing modular project.  For some reason, eclipse seems to think that jdk.crypto.mscapi cannot be resolved to a module.

[image]

I can see the module in the list when I run java --list-modules

I can see the module within eclipse

[image]

Not sure what the problem is here, anyone have any tips?

Comment: I've tried multiple versions of eclipse and multiple JDK's.  I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is no longer displaying the error after changing the compiler compliance level

[image]